# Trying to learn about getter method and while doing so i am getting error with below java code. can some one correct it and explain

Tags: java, constructor

```
class Source {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       // Write code here
        Person p1 = new Person(name:"Ankit");
   }
   public static void printName(Person p){
       System.out.println("name is :"+ p.getName());
   }
}

class Person {
   private String name;
   public Person(String name) {       
       this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName(){
       return this.name;
   }

   // Declare a getter method here
}
```

In the above code I'm getting error for line " Person p1 = new Person(name:"Ankit"); " can someone explain why

Comment: Error is below :
error: ')' expected
        Person p1 = new Person(name:"Ankit");

Comment: Don't confuse the java with javascript or different JVM languages. A java syntax doesn't allow to pass named parameter. So while having a constructor of Person class as `public Person(String name)...`, then to create new object just use `new Person("xyz")` (no `name:` there)

Answer (score 1):

To the constructor in Person class you can only pass String parameters. Below code, `name:` is unknown symbol. That is why it gives an error.

```
Person p1 = new Person(name:"Ankit");
```

You have to change your code as below.

```
Person p1 = new Person("Ankit");
```

Comment: Thanks .... I figured out the mistake seeing your comment. Basically intellij tell's u that name: Ankit. and I was confused while creating my own code

Answer (score 0):

Person p1 = new Person("Ankit");

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you have declared for the Person constructor is a String. When you call the constructor you are passing `name` which is not part of how you declared a Person is constructed.
 The argument you pass when you say `new Person(//some argument)` is copied into the parameter it corresponds to in the constructor declaration and used as you have specified there. Since you are assigning a value into a variable of type ***String*** you must only pass a ***String***.
 You may do this by:
1. Passing a String literal as the argument: 
2. Passing another variable of type String. 
3. Instantiating a new String object in the argument

```
    // First way
    Person p1 = new Person("Ankit");

    // Second way
    String s = "Ankit";
    Person p1 = new Person(s);

    // Third way
    Person p1 = new Person(new String("Ankit"));
```

Comment: and a third way `new Person(new String("Ankit"));`

Comment: Forgot about that one! @itwasntme appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> In the above code I'm getting error for line " Person p1 = new Person(name:"Ankit"); " can someone explain why

It is because your syntax to invoke the constructor is incorrect. There is no need to indicate the parameter.

Just do it as:

```
Person p1 = new Person("Ankit");
```

In case you were wondering how does Java knows which parameter you were referring to when you don't indicate the parameter. It follows the order of the parameters when you create the constructor (same for method invocation):

Let say you have `name` and `nick name` (both are String):

```
//Constructor
//1st param: name
//2nd param: nickName
public Person(String name, String nickName){
    this.name = name;
    this.nickName = nickName;
}

//Creating Person object
Person p = new Person("Rowan Atkinson", "Bean");   //name:Rowan Atkinson, nickName:Bean
                           ^              ^
                      // 1st param     2nd param
```

Comment: nicely said, I'd sugges to change the `There is no need to indicate the parameter` to something `you cannot reffer to specific parameter in Java, there is no way of pasing named arguments` or something similar.